# Remove object by id from an array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So this seems pretty straightforward but I cant seem to get it to work.I have a document in mongodb and i m using mongoose All i need to do is find user by id, get the document and delete one specified object from an array of objects. Here is the Structure:

```
report:[
   {
     asset_report_id:234,
     name:'somethign,
    },
    {
     asset_report_id:23,
     name:'somethign,
    },
   {
     asset_report_id:111,
     name:'somethign,
    }
]
```

I tried this :

```
User.findOne({_id: request.decodedTokenData.userId})
        .exec()
        .then(user=>{
          const result = user.reports.find( ({ asset_report_id }) => asset_report_id === assetID );
          console.log('IN FIND',result);
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Now i do get the result which is great and i can delete but isn't there a method to do it with mongoose directly? More alongthe lines of plain mongo version of :

```
db.removeObject.update( {'_id':ObjectId("5c6ea036a0c51185aefbd14f")},
 {$pull:{"reports":{"asset_report_id":234}}},false,true);
```

Comment: Can you try: `{$pull:{"report":{"asset_report_id":234}}}` ?

Comment: like this ```User.update({_id:request.decodedTokenData.userId},{$pull:{"reports":{"asset_report_id":234}}});```  correct me in the syntax if its wrong thanks

Comment: Yes, but change reports -> report as your sample data's array doesn't end with "s"

Comment: this worked thankyou! although it should use ```updateOne``` update is deprecated :) you can answer this below as well i'll accept it since you helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the correct solution is:

```
await User.updateOne( {'_id':ObjectId("5c6ea036a0c51185aefbd14f")},
   {$pull:{"report":{"asset_report_id":234}}},false,true)
```

since the data model contains "report" array